# NSdateFormatter - weird issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I'm trying to solve a very weird problem. In my app I'm using NSXMLParser to parse feeds.
I have a pubDate tag to parse as well.

I have many varied date formats to parse to the NSDate, and most of them I'm able to parse. With 1 of them I have problem though:

```
<pubDate>2013-04-17T12:22:00.0</pubDate>
```

Here is my date formatting code:

```
NSArray *dateFormats = @[@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S",
@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm Z",
@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",
@"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss",@"EEE,dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];

NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
assert(inputFormatter != nil);
NSLocale *loacle = [[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
assert(loacle != nil);
[inputFormatter setLocale:loacle];

NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentPubDate];
NSLog(@"%@",dateString);
NSDate *inputDate = nil;
for (NSString *dateFormat in dateFormats) {
    [inputFormatter setDateFormat:dateFormat];
    inputDate = [inputFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    if (inputDate) {
        break;
    }
}

NSLocale *hebrow = [[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"he_IL"];
NSDateFormatter *outputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
outputFormatter.locale = hebrow;
[outputFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:3600*2]];
[outputFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
[outputFormatter setTimeStyle:NSTimeZoneNameStyleShortStandard];
NSString *outputDate = [outputFormatter stringFromDate:inputDate];
```

When I'm debugging I can see that `dateString` has a pub date but with `\n` at the end.
It looks like this `@"2013-04-17T12:22:00.0\n"`.

But with `NSLog(@"%@",dateString);` I get this:

```
2013-04-17 18:10:37.769 AppName[11651:f803] 2013-04-17T17:56:58.0
2013-04-17 18:10:47.674 AppName[11651:f803] 2013-04-17T17:17:28.0
2013-04-17 18:10:49.990 AppName[11651:f803] 2013-04-17T16:27:36.0
```

So the date doesn't get displayed. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: since dateString comes from currentPubDate, have you checked to see if currentPubDate has a "\n" at the end?

Comment: yes currentPubDate has /n as well..
i really dont know where this /n comes from.
i have 15 feed sites, all work great only with this one i have the problems..

Comment: so the issue is not with NSDateFormatter, but with NSXMLParser; show us the parsing code.

Comment: you could also try changing the first format string to @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S'\n'" as an experiment (I don't know if that will work).

Comment: @RickTrapp:  The text at the end is "/n" and not '\n' according to question....

Comment: i already tried to add '\n' its not working. and as i said, the xmlparser is not the problem because another feeds are working great with him.

Comment: have you tried with NSString *dateString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",currentPubDate] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""]; ? (yes, it is quite ugly to remove line breaks like that)

Comment: Note that many XML parsers have an option which specifies whether whitespace in the text between tags is considered "significant" or not.  You're likely picking up the `\n` because `</pubDate>` is on a separate line from the date, and the option is specified to consider whitespace significant.